# How do i just send stuff to the internett?

Tags: c#

Im making a logging app and just want to send stuff. Right now im using HttpWebRequest and Stream to send a post message to my webserver so i can observe the stats online.

However, and really often, the sending of the data times out and that messes up my application totally as it does things in a Forms.Timer tick action.

Is there another way to just send stuff to the net? I dont really care if it gets thru or not and getting back a response, i just want to push data to my php script :D

Comment: I think you just have to handle error cases like that. All sorts of this can go wrong when you're using external services.

Comment: Post your code, it should work.

Comment: "How do i just send stuff to the internett?" should be an SO meme.

Comment: We may have just witnessed a birth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP is designed for that. It can lose or reorder packets and doesn't need a response from the server.

But I don't know if you can(or want to) create a UDP server in php.

One alternative is having a thread which does the sending. And the other threads just enqueue log-entries into a thread-safe queue emptied by the sending thread.

Comment: This. Http is not a guaranteed delivery protocol, end of story.

Comment: think the best way to go about it is to do it in a separate thread

Answer (score 1):

On your website you could host a webservice and from the WinForms client you could call asynchronous the webservice to send your data, this way the app will not block.